# Does JS have name binding operations?

Tags: javascript, name-binding

I'm a newbie to js. Let me illustrate my question with a few examples.

#### Code 1

```
var temp = { key: "value" };
var data = ["v1", "v2"];
var result = [];
for (var i in data) {
    var newdata = temp; /** Note here! **/
    newdata.key = data[i];
    result.push(newdata);
}
console.log(result);
// [ { key: 'v2' }, { key: 'v2' } ]
```

The `result` here is unexpected.

#### Code 2

```
var temp = { key: "value" };
var data = ["v1", "v2"];
var result = [];
for (var i in data) {
    var newdata = { key: "value" }; /* Note here! */
    newdata.key = data[i];
    result.push(newdata);
}
console.log(result);
// [ { key: 'v1' }, { key: 'v2' } ]
```

Now the `result` is what I want.

It looks like the [name binding operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228461/understanding-pythons-name-binding) in Python. But I googled a lot and could not get a satisfied answer. So I have to turn to stackoverflow for help.

#### My question:

Does JS have a name binding operation similar with Python? If not, why do these two piece of codes get different results?

#### [Edit]

I know about **reference** in C++, and **name binding** in Python. And I'm also aware of the differences between these two.

The only thing I was confused with was: In JS, is it **reference** or **name binding**? Or something else?

Thanks to all the comments, I totally understand it's similar with **name binding** rather than **reference**.
(As I can't find any button to closed this question, I add the answer here.)

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. That is all.

Comment: FWIW: JavaScript and Python variables work *identically* in this regard: an assignment does *not* create/copy/clone a new object. (Assignment can create a 'new' immutable value [eg. number, bool, string {not: String}], this case is are generally not relevant to talk about as the immutable nature prevents the same state-modification observations.)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That is misleading in the larger context of languages (eg. compare C++) and also in context of "passing" (eg. to a function). JavaScript, like Python, is Call By [Object] Sharing which is a form of Call By Value. There is no need for the term "reference" (although it is often confused with the colloquial ".. refers to ..") and in fact, the specification does not use the term for this behavior. Instead of "the variable x references object y", I opt for "the variable x names object y" to avoid the terminology entirely and this is similar to Python's "name binding" terminology.

Comment: Objects are passed/assigned by value, and that value is a reference.