# Store variables in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had this Python 2.7 code which queries the movement limits from a device:

```
pan_low_limit = int(self.send_query("PN", 2))
pan_high_limit = int(self.send_query("PX", 2))
tilt_low_limit = int(self.send_query("TN", 2))
tilt_high_limit = int(self.send_query("TX", 2))
```

I thought I could write this nicer as:

```
limits = [(pan_low_limit, "PN"), (pan_high_limit, "PX"), (tilt_low_limit, "TN"), (tilt_high_limit, "TX")]
for v, c in limits:
    v = int(self.send_query(c, 2))
    print("Result from {}: {}".format(c, v))
print(limits)
print("tilt_low_limit: {}".format(tilt_low_limit))
```

Print statements are to find what's going on. When I run this, I get the following output (these four variables had been initialized with value 1 before this piece of code):

```
Result from PN: -27067
Result from PX: 27067
Result from TN: -27999
Result from TX: 9333
[(1, 'PN'), (1, 'PX'), (1, 'TN'), (1,'TX')]
tilt_low_limit: 1
PN: 1
```

I don't really get what's going on. It seems like the value of v in `"v = int(self.send_query(c, 2))"` is what I'd expect, but at the next line, these variables have the old values again?

Comment: Python's variables are not symbolic names for memory addresses (like in C or Pascal) but just names bound to an object. Rebinding a name only make this name pointing to another object, it doesn't affect the object that was previously bound to this name. You want to read this for more in-depth explanations: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean, so I'll read up on the link you've provided.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that link was very helpful and clears up a lot. Recommended reading. I also found that pythontutor.com is helpful to visualize what variables/objects are doing in small snippets of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python a symbolic name (like `pan_low_limit` in your code) is a reference to a value (like "-27067").

When one name is assigned to the other (as happens for `limits` and `v` in your code), the new name becomes an additional reference to that value. In your case, in the first iteration right before the assignment, the names: `pan_low_limit`, `limits[0][0]` and `v` all refer to the same value:

[image: before]

However, when you assign (or *bind*) a name to a new value, only that name will refer to the new value. In your case, after the assignment, you will have:

[image: after]

To obtain the result that you want, you should *change* the variable, instead of reassigning it, so that all the references will refer to the same new value. However, **integers are immutable** in Python, so you cannot change it. 
The solution is to use something that is mutable, a *list* for example.

If you had a mutable variable, the original value could be changed to have the result that you are expecting. You can see this difference in the following two snippets:

Using integers:

```
pan_low_limit = 1
pan_high_limit = 1
tilt_low_limit = 1
tilt_high_limit = 1

limits = [(pan_low_limit, "PN"), (pan_high_limit, "PX"), (tilt_low_limit, "TN"), (tilt_high_limit, "TX")]
for v, c in limits:
    v = 2
    print("Result from {}: {}".format(c, v))
print(limits)
print("tilt_low_limit: {}".format(tilt_low_limit))
```

Result:

```
Result from PN: 2
Result from PX: 2
Result from TN: 2
Result from TX: 2
[(1, 'PN'), (1, 'PX'), (1, 'TN'), (1, 'TX')]
tilt_low_limit: 1
```

Using lists, we can modify the value, instead of reassigning it:

```
pan_low_limit = [1]
pan_high_limit = [1]
tilt_low_limit = [1]
tilt_high_limit = [1]

limits = [(pan_low_limit, "PN"), (pan_high_limit, "PX"), (tilt_low_limit, "TN"), (tilt_high_limit, "TX")]
for v, c in limits:
    v[0] = 2
    print("Result from {}: {}".format(c, v))
print(limits)
print("tilt_low_limit: {}".format(tilt_low_limit))
```

Result:

```
Result from PN: [2]
Result from PX: [2]
Result from TN: [2]
Result from TX: [2]
[([2], 'PN'), ([2], 'PX'), ([2], 'TN'), ([2], 'TX')]
tilt_low_limit: [2]
```

Reference: [link](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Thanks @bruno desthuilliers for pointing out flaws in a previous answer.

Comment: Sorry but stating that it's "similar to an assignment in C" is just plain wrong. If you were to rewrite the C example with a struct instead of an int, you'd find out that changing one of the field of `a` would not impact `b[0] ` - since it would indeed _copy_ the "value" - while in Python (using any mutable  object instead), mutating the object via the iteration variable (or any other name pointing to this object) DOES change the one stored in the list. To make a long story short: Python's "variables" have nothing in common with C variables and you cannot explain one it terms of the other.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was indeed over-simplifying. I have now updated the answer.

Comment: that's better but still wrong ;-) The fact that ints are immuable is actually totally irrelevant, the problem is that rebinding a name only makes the name refer to another object. The behavior would be the same with mutable objects. The difference is not between mutable and immutable objects but between mutating and rebinding.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. Probably a more detailed explanation is needed. It does make a difference if the variable is mutable or immutable, as you can see in my example. Look also at this answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228461/understanding-pythons-name-binding 
I think you should provide a new answer with details on your theory, references and some code that proves it. I will be happy to upvote it :)

Comment: Yes, I agree that in one case I mutate it and in the other case I do not, because it is *immutable* :). I also agree that, if your answer is "that's how python works, period.", it is better if you do not provide a new answer. Your own reference clearly say why mutable and immutable are relevant in this scenario. The SO question that I linked explains this also.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I mean. Can you please run this code https://pastebin.com/KPkzER0D  and report what you observe ? Yes, the result is just the same as with ints, despite lists being mutable. That's what I mean when I say that mutability is irrelevant wrt/ how binding work. Of course your solution relies on mutating the list  instead of rebinding it, which is a totally different operation (nb : `somelist[index] = value` is only syntactic sugar for `somelist.__setitem__(index, value)`, so it's a mutation, not  a binding).

Comment: I see now what you mean. The mutability is important if you consider the question and the result that he wants to achieve (that cannot be done with an immutable variable). I updated the answer, making this distinction more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
for i, (v, c) in enumerate(limits):
    limits[i] = int(self.send_query(c, 2))
```

`v =` does not change the value in `limits`, it merely changes the value of the reference/variable `v`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. After the 'for' loop, limits = [-27067, 27067, -27999, 9333]. However the values of the variables pan_low_limit/... are all still 1.

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD Yes, there is no way to modify the variables in the way you'd like (unless they're global, in which case you can modify the `globals()` dict, but don't do that). So I'm suggesting a reasonable alternative.