# how the local variable are stored and returned in memory (python)?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I always used python without thinking its memory management. But, I have a big question about how it deals memory.

```py
def func1():
    local_var = 1
    print(id(local_var))  # memory address of local_var (stored in stack variable) -> 1
    return local_var


# value copied, and local_var_different_scope points another memory address
local_var_different_scope = func1() 
print(id(local_var_different_scope))  # -> 2
local_var_different_scope = 2
print(id(local_var_different_scope)) # -> 3
```

1. I expected that #1 and #2 would print different address, but it was same.
   Doesn't copying happen in Python when a function returns? If it happens, I think 1 and 2 need to point different address because it is located in different function.
2. Also, I wondered that 2 and 3 are different. I think if I change the value, then the value in the memory are changed but the address remains the same.
   For example, below C code shows the same address.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    printf("%p\n", &a);
    
    a = 2;
    printf("%p\n", &a); // same as above!

    return 0;
}
```

I would be really appreciated If you suggest any materials to understand this problem in depth. Thank you!

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228502/202168 "In Python, a variable name can be thought of as a binding to a value"

Comment: Python never copies anything unless you explicitly call a function like `copy.copy()`. All data is passed as references.

Comment: `id()` tells you the ID of the value, not the variable. If you want a C analogy, every variable is a pointer, and `id` returns the pointer value, not the address of the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python all assignments are ***references to objects*** - in your case integer objects (everything is an object in Python!)

So in this snippet you've created a `1` (`id=xyz`) object and returned that object (`id=xyz`) to `local_var_different_scope`. So `local_var_different_scope` now references the `id=xyz` object (which is the integer `1` you created).

```
def func1():
    local_var = 1
    print(id(local_var))  # memory address of local_var (stored in stack variable) -> 1
    return local_var
```

You then reassigned `local_var_different_scope` to ***reference*** a new integer object `2` (`id=abc`). Naturally, the `id` of `2` is different from `1`.

Hope this helps!

---

## How could an object persist past it's function call?

Simply put, it persists because the **object** returned is assigned to a variable, and Python is smart enough to know that!

Here's another interesting experiment:

```
def return_x():
    x = 45
    print(id(x)) # id=123
    return x
fake_x = return_x()
print(id(fake_x)) # id=123
print(x) # NameError 'x' is not defined
```

One might then guess that since `x` is returned, it can be referenced - but that is not the case!

To drive the point home, each ***assignment is a ***reference*** to an object*** in Python. `x` simply referenced the object `45` with `id=123`!

`return x` returned the ***referenced object*** but not the variable `x`!